# Android NFC card emulation feasibility

Tags: android, nfc, identifier, mifare

Is it possible today, without hacks, to emulate an NFC card with NFC-enabled Android devices?

The target use case is for people to identify themselves through their mobile phone instead of their NFC member cards. The TagID can be different from existing cards TagIDs but has to stay unique per device, and shouldn't change after the first use.

Multiple similar questions exist but no answers were recent and/or straightforward. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with recent good news from Android 4.4. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html